# How to update a column in one table from a column in another table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables A and B.
In table A I have a char column and integer column for many2one(ID) of column B.

In table B I have same char column.

Now i have to compare char columns of both tables and update the respecting ID of table B to table A.

Table A

```
| Name | ID of B |
|------|---------|
| ABC  |         |
| BCD  |         |
| CDF  |         |
```

Table B

```
| ID | Name |
|----|------|
|  1 | CDF  |
|  2 | ABC  |
|  3 | BCD  |
```

How to do this in UPDATE query, if not possible how to do that in INSERT query for whole table. Im having 100s of record in table.

Comment: I've not tried it but probably you need something like:
 
`UPDATE table_A SET table_A.ID = table_B.ID WHERE table_A.NAME = table_B.NAME`

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. This is working.UPDATE A
  SET A.ID = B.id
FROM B
WHERE A.name = B.name;